# Python: removes rows from a dataframe when the values of a singal list match the values of the column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (DF) and a list(L). I want to remove the rows from the dataframe if the values of DF['A'] match the values of the list L.

Example:

[image]

I tried to code this to remove the rows:

```
            majorCur = majorCur[~majorCur['datetime'].isin(combineMajorSecondList)]
```

But, the result looks not right when I look at the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.loc` for this

`majorCur = majorCur.loc[~majorCur['datetime'].isin(combineMajorSecondList), :]`

Comment: Is there any other method to implement?

Comment: This is the method you will need to use
`new_df = df.loc[~df[column_name].isin(list_of_items), :]` will work. Its hard to help without code to actually test as you may have something else wrong upstream

Comment: In particular see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on including reproducible examples in questions. Try including code that can immediately be copied into a python interpreter and will produce the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I saved the table to a text file. And checked the nrows was I expected. But, I don't know what's wrong, when I checked the table through Debug in Pycharm, the nrows was not right.